# Are there some practical examples that use Object::*

Tags: c++

I just heard of that there is a kind of type like this,a point to Object member. Here is it

```
class Point{float x, y;};
float Point::*p2 = &Point::x;
```

but I haven't use before,and wonder some-body really use it.Do you have any experience of that?

Comment: Have a look at libraries like boost::intrusive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is useful if you want to apply the same treatment to members without duplicating the code.

```
vector<Point> points; // suppose it has many elements

vector<double> Project(const vector<Point> points, int Point::* coord)
{
    vector<double> result;
    for (auto& p: points)
        result.push_back(p.*coord);
    return result;
}

// usage:
vector<double> Xs = Project(points, &Point::x);
vector<double> Ys = Project(points, &Point::y);
```

There are many other usages as well, for instance fast delegates ([link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11015/The-Impossibly-Fast-C-Delegates)).

Comment: @user974349 : this is a C++11 feature, available on GCC 4.5+ and MSVC 11 (beta). You may prefer `std::for_each(begin(points), end(points), [&result](const Point& p) { result.push_back(p); }` with MSVC 10.

Answer (score 0):

Those are [pointers to class members](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html) and are used for example to implement various functor classes (e.g.: `boost::function` or `std::function`).

Answer (score 0):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn

or

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/mem_fun/

Answer (score -1):

```
class Point {
   public: //public variables (can be accessed by outsider)
   float x, y;

   private: //private variables if you have any

};
```

Now to create an object you would do `Point p`, and you can access the elements by doing `p.x` and `p.y`, just like you would with a `struct` object.

If you want to create a class pointer, do `Point *p`, now if you want to access `x, y`, then you would do `p->a` and `p->b`. If you have another object `Point t`, and you want assign address of `t` to `p`, then you can do `p = &t`.

Comment: I guess you are missing the point of the question. This is just member access, not pointer-to-members.